# apache filematch: how to match extension except some files

Tags: regex, apache

Currently we have:

```
# ----------------------------------------+++++----
<FilesMatch "(?i)(\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|\.txt)">
 Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

But we need to allow `robots.txt` and `ads.txt`.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?i)(\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots|ads)\.txt)$
```

`(?<!robots|ads)\.txt` not `robots` or `ads` followed by `.txt`.

`$` the end of the line/string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dqxQRv/1)